# Parsing JSON key/value pairs with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json

I have a .NET project. I'm using the JSON.NET library. I need to use this library to parse some JSON. My JSON looks like this:

```
{"1":"Name 1","2":"Name 2"}
```

The object is really just a list of key/value pairs. I am trying to figure out how to use JSON.NET to 1) parse this JSON and 2) loop through the key/value pairs. Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

The only thing I see is de-serializing into a strongly-typed object.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you generate this JSON? Will it always be 1 and 2 as the keynames?

Comment: Well what have you tried so far in terms of JSON.NET? It looks like you should be able to parse this as a `JObject`, or convert it to a `Dictionary<string, string>` very easily...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: Please post some code you've tried so we can help you further.

Comment: This question looks like the other side of this coin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635808/serialize-objects-as-json#29635808

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can deserialize to `Dictionary<string, string>`

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
foreach(var kv in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kv.Key + ":" + kv.Value);
}
```

Since JObject implements `IDictionary`, you can also simply use `JObject.Parse`

```
var dict = JObject.Parse(@"{""1"":""Name 1"",""2"":""Name 2""}");
```

Answer (score 6):

Below is the json Where subratings have key value pair

```
{  
"data": [    
{      
"id": "288560300",      
"lang": "en", 

"subratings":     {     

"Cleanliness": "5",

"Sleep Quality": "5",

"Service": "5"
  }
}
]}

public void LoadJsonKeyValuePair(string json)
{  
Rootobject item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
}

public class Rootobject
{
[JsonProperty("data")]
public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
[JsonProperty("id")]
public string id { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("lang")]
public string lang { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("subratings")]
public Dictionary<string, object> subratings { get; set; }
}
```

You can use Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize this object

Comment: Could you perhaps explain how to list the key/value pair with this example? I have a similar setup. Its not clear how to access the key/value pair with whats here.

Comment: is it possible to select only a few keys from the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Hi all felt I should also share this

The above answer works for me using text box in asp.ne t

```
var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>
(json_Incoming_fromServer);
foreach(var keyvalue in jsonData)
{

   textBox.text = keyvalue.Value; // this will only display the value of that
   // attribute / key 

}
```

thanks to EZI