# Serialize objects as JSON

Tags: c#

I have a C# app, that has an object, that looks like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ParentId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

I then get a list of objects like this:

```
var myObjects = MyObject.LoadAll();
```

I need to create a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{ "1":"James", "2":"Bill", "3":"Andrew" }
```

1, 2, and 3 are the Id values of the list of MyObject entities. "James", "Bill", and "Andrew" are the values of the "Name" property from each object. How do I create a JSON object in this manner using just the two properties?

Thank you!

Comment: Although your requested JSON is valid as JSON, it's a very poor choice as a serialized object (because it doesn't represent a serialized object... at all).  Any control over what is needed?

Comment: Try http://json2csharp.com/  just copy/paste your json and it will create your classes and properties for you.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a json like that.

Comment: @ShiftySituation VS's Paste-Special-JSON As Classes will do that for you

Comment: The JSON example you posted isn't wise, as it is not a representation of what you're saying you want it to be. What you have shown is an object with 3 numbered properties whose values are the corresponding names. What you should be looking for is `[ {"Id":1, "Name":"James"}, {"Id":2, "Name":"Bill"}, {"Id":3, "Name":"Andrew"} ]`. This actually makes sense, and is able to be easily parsed from a C# object. Otherwise, you're going to have to create a custom serializer and it gets a LOT messier.

Comment: Have a look at [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Comment: xam developer, See how your classmate deserializes it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632593/parsing-json-key-value-pairs-with-json-net

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq and Json.Net library for that.

```
var myObjects = MyObject.LoadAll();
var forSerialization = myObjects.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Name);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(forSerialization);
```